# how to hidden a group or label of group

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I'm using Odoo 11 and I want to hide a group

```
<page name="sales_purchases" string="Sales &amp; Purchases">
    <group name="container_row_2">
        <group string="Sale" name="sale">
            <field name="customer"/>
            <field name="user_id"/>
        </group>
        <group string="Purchase" name="purchase">
            <field name="supplier"/>
        </group>
        <group string="Misc">
            <field name="ref"/>
            <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company" options="{'no_create': True}"/>
            <field name="industry_id" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_company', '=', False)]}" options="{'no_create': True}"/>
        </group>
    </group>
</page>
```

In my XML, I'm using this code to hide the field, but the label of the group still shows up.

How do I fix this?

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='trust']" position="replace">
    <field name="trust" attrs="{'invisible':[('customer','=',False)]}"/>
</xpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same attrs on group tag :

```
attrs="{'invisible': [('is_company', '=', False)]}"
```